# Why PowerShell $Matches Hashtable automatic variable is not returning all matches?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, automatic-variable

I'm using `Named Captures` in `PowerShell`. But the following example is not returning all matches. All the lines in the following code return correct output - except the lines 7 and 8. I was expecting `$Matches.1` and `$Matches.2` to return `v` and `A` respectively. But these two lines of code return nothing.

**Question**: What I may be missing here or maybe not correctly understanding here?

**Ref**: Lates [version 7.4 of PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.4)

```
 PS> $string = 'The last logged on user was A\v'
 PS> $string -match 'was (?<domain>.+)\\(?<user>.+)'
 PS> $Matches.domain #returns A
 PS> $Matches.user #returns v
 PS> $Matches.count #returns 3
 PS> $Matches.0 #returns was A\v
 PS> $Matches.1 #returns nothing
 PS> $Matches.2 #returns nothing
 PS> $Matches #returns the following output
```

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| domain | A |
| user | v |
| 0 | was A\v |

Comment: The $Matches hashtable contains only the first occurrence of any matching pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [automatic **`$Matches`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) is a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) whose entries are **populated as follows**:

- The entry with key (index) `0` (type `[int]`) is *always* present, representing the *whole* match.
- Additional entries are only populated if there are *capture groups* in the regex, as follows:

  - Any *named* capture group (e.g. `(?<domain>.+)`) is represented by an entry with a key of the same name (type `[string]`) - *only* (it doesn't *also* get a *positional* entry - see below).

    - For instance, `$Matches.domain` or, alternatively, `$Matches['domain']`, returns the substring matched by the example capture group, if any.
  - Any - remaining or only - *unnamed* and therefore *positional* capture groups (e.g. `(.+)`) are represented *in order*, with *indices*, namely as entries with `[int]`-typed keys starting with `1`.

    - For instance, `$Matches.1` or, alternatively, `$Matches[1]`, would return the substring that the example capture group matched, assuming it is the first positional (unnamed) one in the regex.

---

It follows from the above that in your case `$Matches` *only* has `'domain'` and `'user'` entries beyond the always-present `0` entry, because only *named* capture groups, with these names, are present.

Also note that the fact that `$Matches` is implemented as a [`[hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) implies that its entries are *inherently unordered* - thus, you cannot rely on the *enumeration order* of the entries to be meaningful (via `.GetEnumerator()` for the entries as a whole, or via `.Keys` or `.Values` for the keys and values, respectively), and even the entries with keys that are conceptually *indices* - for the whole match and any unnamed / positional capture groups - are typically *not* reflected in their numerical order.

---

**Important considerations of `$Matches` use**:

- It is **automatically populated** by:

  - **`-match`**, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch):

    - **Only** if the **LHS is a *single* string (object) *and* a match is found**, i.e. only when `-match` returns `$true`

      - Notably, a preexisting `$Matches` result is *left untouched* if `$false` is returned, so **`$Matches` should only be consulted after receiving `$true`**.
      - `-match` only ever looks for *one* match in the input string.

        - [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) is a green-lit, but as yet unimplemented proposal to complement it with a `-matchall` operator.
      - A simple example:

        ```
         $str = 'Maroon 5'
         if ($str -match '(o)+. \d') {
           Write-Verbose -Verbose "Matched: $str - `$Matches contains:"
           $Matches
         } else {
           # NOTE: $Matches was NOT populated
           #       nor were previous results reset.
           Write-Verbose -Verbose "Did not match: $str"
         }
        ```
    - By contrast, with *array-valued* LHS, `-match` - [like other comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features) - acts as a *filter* that returns the sub-array of matching input strings, and doesn't populate `$Matches` at all (nor resets any previous results).
  - the **[`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch)** statement, if used with the **`-Regex` switch**:

    - Specifically, string-based branch conditionals are then treated as [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) and the associated action block - which is only entered in case of a match - then has `$Matches` populated.
    - A simple example:

      ```
       switch -Regex ('Maroon 5', 'foo') {
         '(o)+. \d' { Write-Verbose -Verbose "Matched: $_ - `$Matches contains:"; $Matches }
         default    { Write-Verbose -Verbose "Did not match: $_"  }
       }
      ```